# select sum(a), sum(b where c=1) from db; sql conditions in select statement

Tags: sql, select

i guess i just lack the keywords to search, but this is burning on my mind:

how can i add a condition to the sum-function in the select-statement like

select sum(a), sum(b where c=1) from db;?

this means, i want to see the sum of column a and the sum of column b, but only of the records in column b of which column c has the value 1.

the output of heidi just says "bad syntac near WHERE". may there be any other way?

thanks in advance and best regards from Berlin, joachim

Comment: What is your database engine?

Comment: mssql - syntax of Joe just worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(case when c=1 then b else 0 end)
```

This technique is useful when you need a lot of aggregates on the same set of data - you can query the entire table without applying a `where` filter, and have a bunch of these which give you aggregated data for a specific filter.

It's also useful when you need a lot of counts based on filters - you can do sums of 1 or 0:

```
select sum(case when {somecondition} then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: I think he still wants sum(a) as well.

Comment: @Gratzy Yeah, you can have as many columns as you want in the query - this just shows the one specific column that is applicable to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The exact syntax may differ depending on the database engine, however it will be along the lines of

```
SELECT
    sum(a),
    sum(CASE WHEN c = 1 THEN b ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    db
```